# How can I set the theme/package just for a custom module?

Tags: theme

I have a module that adds some custom content that I would really like to display with a different theme to that used for the main store.

The main store theme has a theme that knocks out the CSS etc for things like toolbars, rather than fix this awful theme I would prefer to revert back to a version of the default theme, just for this one module.

I have seen on the category pages that there are options to set a different theme, however, I do not know where to begin when it comes to doing this for myself with one particular module.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.